# Can an extern Function Pointer be used in a callback in the C language?

Tags: c, callback, extern

I am studying callback in the c language. In the examples, the Function Pointer is passed as an argument to a downstream function which in turn uses to "callback" an upstream function. Can it be passed as an extern variable instead of an argument?

I tried to google passing a function pointer as extern but did not find anything relevant. Probably for good reason (I.e. it's either bad coding or doesn't work or is just plain stupid).

/* callback.c */

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"reg_callback.h"

/* callback function definition goes here */
void my_callback(void)
{
    printf("inside my_callback\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    /* initialize function pointer to
    my_callback */
    callback ptr_my_callback=my_callback;                           
    printf("This is a program demonstrating function callback\n");
    /* register our callback function */
    register_callback(ptr_my_callback);                             
    printf("back inside main program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

/* reg_callback.h */

```
typedef void (*callback)(void);
void register_callback(callback ptr_reg_callback);
```

/* reg_callback.c */

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"reg_callback.h"

/* registration goes here */
void register_callback(callback ptr_reg_callback)
{
    printf("inside register_callback\n");
    /* calling our callback function my_callback */
    (*ptr_reg_callback)();                                  
}
```

this worked as expected. It produced the following output:

```
This is a program demonstrating function callback
inside register_callback
inside my_callback
back inside main program
```

Could the same thing have been accomplished using an function pointer stored in extern variable instead of passing it as argument?

thanks
Kial

Comment: Your "register_callback" function isn't registering anything--it's just calling the function passed to it; not sure what your intention there was. But sure, function pointers in C can be held in global variables. That's typically what a "register" type function does--saves the pointer in a static variable hidden from the caller so that it can only be invoked later by some library function.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Crocker. The example comes from a book. I understood that "register_callback" had nothing to do with a HW register, I assumed the original author just meant to save it. From Mr. Bollinger's answer, it sounds like poor code practice to save the function pointer in an extern. Would saving it in a static variable that was hidden be acceptable coding practice? If so, could you give me an example of how this code might look like ? thanks for your support and advice.

Comment: "Register" in this context is a verb, usually meaning something like "Hey, I'm giving you something to identify me that I want you to save for later."

Answer (score 1):

> Could the same thing have been accomplished using an function pointer stored in extern variable instead of passing it as argument?

Yes, in your simple example case.  It is the pointer *value* that is important, not the mechanism by which the value is conveyed to its point of use.

But in real-world callback cases, it is often impossible to rely on an external variable to still be holding the wanted value when the time comes to call the callback, as its value may be modified between.  Moreover, callback interfaces are normally intended to support communication patterns involving separate components, such that there can be no shared convention to know what external variable to use.

Overall, external (a.k.a. "global") variables have bad code smell, and are rarely a good solution for programs or libraries larger than toys and quick one-offs.

Comment: thank you so much Mr. Bollinger. I  suspected that it was bad coding practice. Now I know why. I've inherited some code in which a downstream function incorrectly attempts to call an upstream function. I was trying to avoid significantly modifying the code to pass the Function Pointer through the function hierarchy and thought about this extern short cut. Now that you explained it, I see that I need to bite the bullet and do it right. thanks again.